# How do I say something like HEAD-1 in svn?

Tags: svn, revision

I want to refer to a revision just before head or n-revisions before HEAD or something like that.

Comment: In what context - to provide to a check-in hook, or just in general?

Comment: @synthesizerpatelIn the context of day-to-day use with svn client. I dunno nothing about check-in hooks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short - you can't without running a command. With check-in hooks you can get access to 'the version before this one', otherwise you need to query it dynamically. Here's an example that populates a shell variable with the revision of the current head, minus one.

```
HEAD_MINUS_ONE=$(svn info http://svn/path/to/head | grep ^Revision | awk '{print $2-1}')
```

Answer (score 9):

There's are a few built in revision key words in Subversion which may solve most of your problems:

- `BASE`: This is the revision used in your current working directory.
- `HEAD`: This is the current tip of the branch.
- `COMMITTED`: This is the last committed revision of a file before `BASE`.
- `PREV`: This is the last changed revision from `BASE`. It's pretty much COMMITTED-1.

For everything else, you'll need to do a calculation as [synthesizeerpatel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394724/368630) showed you.

Answer (score 0):

@David W. provided part of the asnwer, but for people lazy like me. 
Just use

`svn up -r PREV`